# Boost libs 1.64.0 and Eclipse Luna

Tags: c++, linux, eclipse, boost

I'm trying to make Boost libs to work with Eclipse Luna (I know it's an old version but I'm tied to work with it).
My system is a Linux Mint 18.1.
I downloaded, unpacked and installed the libraries following [this guide](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html).
I ended up with unpacked libraries in my home folder and compiled ones in usr/local/include/boost folder.
Next I added the latter to the LD LIBRARY PATH and resetted the ldconfig.

At this point I copied some code on an empty C++ project.
The header I'm using is "share_ptr.hpp" so I set the #include .
After that I added the include path to the included headers under Project -> Properties -> C/C++ General -> Paths and Symbols.
I added the path /usr/local/include as included directory.

When I build I get the error: "No such file or directory".
If I #include the header with the absolute path, I can find the file but I get another error cause this .hpp file has references to the "relative" path /boost/smart_ptr/share_ptr, so it doesn't find all those headers:

```
#ifndef BOOST_SMART_PTR_HPP_INCLUDED
#define BOOST_SMART_PTR_HPP_INCLUDED
#include <boost/config.hpp>
#include <boost/scoped_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/scoped_array.hpp>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/shared_array.hpp>
#if !defined(BOOST_NO_MEMBER_TEMPLATES) || defined(BOOST_MSVC6_MEMBER_TEMPLATES)
# include <boost/weak_ptr.hpp>
# include <boost/intrusive_ptr.hpp>
# include <boost/enable_shared_from_this.hpp>
# include <boost/make_shared.hpp>
#endif
#endif // #ifndef BOOST_SMART_PTR_HPP_INCLUDED
```

Looks like to me that Eclipse can't get the include path correctly.

Another thing that I tried was adding the -L  for the linker, but it doesn't work either.

This is what I'm including:

```
#include <vector>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
```

Could you help me to understand what it's going on ?

Adding informations:
CODE:

```
#include <boost/lambda/lambda.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    using namespace boost::lambda;
    typedef std::istream_iterator<int> in;

    std::for_each(
        in(std::cin), in(), std::cout << (_1 * 3) << " " );
}
```

CONSOLE:

```
08:13:11 **** Incremental Build of configuration Build (GNU) for project TESTCODE ****
make all 
make  all-recursive
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/daniele/workspace/TESTCODE'
Making all in src
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/daniele/workspace/TESTCODE/src'
arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-g++  -march=armv7ve -mfpu=neon  -mfloat-abi=hard -mcpu=cortex-a7 --sysroot=/opt/fsl-imx-fb/4.1.15-2.0.1/sysroots/cortexa7hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I..   --sysroot=/opt/fsl-imx-fb/4.1.15-2.0.1/sysroots/cortexa7hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi  -g -O0  --sysroot=/opt/fsl-imx-fb/4.1.15-2.0.1/sysroots/cortexa7hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi -MT TESTCODE.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/TESTCODE.Tpo -c -o TESTCODE.o TESTCODE.cpp
TESTCODE.cpp:11:35: fatal error: boost/lambda/lambda.hpp: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [TESTCODE.o] Error 1
Makefile:398: recipe for target 'TESTCODE.o' failed
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/daniele/workspace/TESTCODE/src'
make: *** [all] Error 2
Makefile:403: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/daniele/workspace/TESTCODE'
Makefile:335: recipe for target 'all' failed

08:13:11 Build Finished (took 84ms)
```

ERRORS:

> Description   Resource    Path    Location    Type fatal error:
>   boost/lambda/lambda.hpp: No such file or
>   directory TESTCODE.cpp    /TESTCODE/src   line 11 C/C++ Problem make: ***
>   [all] Error 2 TESTCODE            C/C++ Problem make[1](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html): *** [all-recursive]
>   Error 1   TESTCODE            C/C++ Problem make[2]: *** [TESTCODE.o] Error
>   1 TESTCODE            C/C++ Problem recipe for target 'all-recursive'
>   failed    Makefile    /TESTCODE   line 403    C/C++ Problem recipe for target
>   'all' failed  Makefile    /TESTCODE   line 335    C/C++ Problem recipe for
>   target 'TESTCODE.o' failed    Makefile    /TESTCODE   line 398    C/C++ Problem

Comment: As a side note I tried to compile the "Build a basic program using Boost" in the guide and I got the same error: Description Resource Path Location Type fatal error: boost/lambda/lambda.hpp: No such file or directory.

Comment: Do you see your /usr/local/include/boost path under your project "Includes" tree in Eclipse Project Explorer?

Comment: @pe3k yes, i can see it

Comment: OK, can you post dump of your "CDT Build Console" as well as your minimal complete source code and full error message?

Comment: Sure I can. In like 12 Hours tho, when i'll ne on my pc at work. Thanks a lot for your help !

Comment: Added requested informations on the question above

Comment: You seem to be using ARM toolchain as your compiler, is this intentional? If yes, try setting include paths for this toolchaing in Properties -> C/C++ Build -> Settings -> [correct toolchain Includes].

Comment: Yes, it's intentional. From Properties -> C/C++ Build -> Settings I can only set Binary Parsers and Error Parsers

Comment: It is still not clear if it is Eclipse problem or Toolchain problem. Try adding new custom directory, create one header file (eg. SomeClass.hpp) with one class. Try adding this folder path as include directory and to your source as #include "SomeClass.hpp". Than add "-v" (verbose) setting to your compiler toolchain and post the output of CDT build console. That should suffice to see if the problem is in CDT settings or not.

Comment: I'm successfully compiling already with custom header folder without problems. Of course I had to add that header workspace folder in the include list. Looks like Eclipse can't solve relative paths outside the workspace.

Comment: Out of desperation I copied the boost folder inside the project, but it doesn't work either.

Comment: Update: I created an Exec project and not a Yocto ADT project, I set the library directory and it compiles.

Comment: Did you see this hint? https://lists.yoctoproject.org/pipermail/yocto/2013-August/015566.html

Comment: And maybe this post will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33180585/c-cmake-boost-arm-cross-compilation

Comment: Yes, but the library I'm testing on is "lambda" and it's header only. No compiling involved. Am I wrong ?

Comment: That is right. Can you publish your build console output when using -v (verbose) compiler flag?

Comment: Added --disable-silent-rules to the configure of Autotools but it has no effect. Any idea ?

Comment: @Podarce, did you select GNU C++ before adding the include directory in the 'includes'?

Comment: Yes, of course I did